# ionic 2 - Remove Border Footer

Tags: ionic2

I have a blue footer like this

```
<ion-footer align="center">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
...
```

But it is showing a shadow style border at the top. How can I remove it. I tried to inspect it but did not find anything.

Comment: It's an background-image for a div .footer-md{background:none;content:""}

Answer (score 28):

Use `no-border` to remove shadows

```
<ion-footer align="center" no-border>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      fsdfda
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

documentation is here : [ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/)

Comment: Hope you can accept this answer no? @Missak Boyajian

Answer (score 15):

In ionic 5 the built in class is slightly different I came across this recently and decided to post an update.

```
<ion-footer class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      fsdfda
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```